# Pagination in django rest, ListAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i'm new in django and i have a little problem in the pagination of objects.

my model:

```
class FacebookBien(models.Model):
uid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
ref_agence = models.IntegerField()
loyer = models.FloatField()
prix = models.FloatField()
ville = models.CharField(max_length=200)
code_postal = models.CharField(max_length=200)
ref_type_bien = models.IntegerField()
surface_totale = models.FloatField()
source = models.CharField(max_length=200)
nombre_de_pieces = models.IntegerField()
date_modification = models.DateTimeField()

class Meta:
    managed = False
    # db_table = 'public\".\"bien_recherche'
    db_table = 'recette_facebook\".\"vue_facebook_bien_recherche'
```

my view:

```
class BienAgence(generics.ListAPIView):
queryset = FacebookBien.objects
pagination_class = SmallPagesPagination

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    res = request.GET
    if FacebookBien.objects.filter(ref_agence=int(kwargs['ref_agence'])).exists():
        toto = self.queryset.filter(ref_agence=int(kwargs['ref_agence']))
        if (res['type'] == 'bien'):
            toto = toto.filter(prix__gte=int(res['p_mini']))
            toto = toto.filter(prix__lte=int(res['p_maxi']))
            if (res['prix'] == 'croissant'):
                toto = toto.order_by('prix')
            elif (res['prix'] == 'decroissant'):
                toto = toto.order_by('-prix')
        else:
            toto = toto.filter(loyer__gte=int(res['p_mini']))
            toto = toto.filter(loyer__lte=int(res['p_maxi']))
            if (res['prix'] == 'croissant'):
                toto = toto.order_by('loyer')
            elif (res['prix'] == 'decroissant'):
                toto = toto.order_by('-loyer')
        if (res['surface'] == 'croissant'):
            toto = toto.order_by('surface_totale')
        elif (res['surface'] == 'decroissant'):
            toto = toto.order_by('-surface_totale')
        elif (res['date'] == 'croissant'):
            toto = toto.order_by('date_creation')
        elif (res['date' == 'decroissant']):
            toto = toto.order_by('-date_creation')
        toto = toto.filter(surface__gte=int(res['s_mini']))
        toto = toto.filter(surface__lte=int(res['s_maxi']))
        serializer = FacebookBienSerializer(toto, many=True) # noqa
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(None)
```

my pagination.py:

```
class SmallPagesPagination(PageNumberPagination):  
page_size = 6
```

The problem is that it does not put me at all 6 objects per page. if i do not override the get method, it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**my_view.py**

```
class BienAgence(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = FacebookBien.objects
    pagination_class = SmallPagesPagination

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        serializer = FacebookBienSerializer(toto, many=True)
        page = self.paginate_queryset(serializer.data)
        return self.get_paginated_response(page)
```

Answer (score -1):

One way is to override the MyOffsetPagination class 
like this

```
from rest_framework.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination

class MyOffsetPagination(LimitOffsetPagination):
    default_limit = 20
    max_limit = 1000
```

and then add this in your view

```
pagination_class = MyOffsetPagination
```

Don't forget to add this in you settings

```
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': (
        'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination'),
    'PAGE_SIZE': (50)
```